# Is it possible in Selenium to close a OS File Select dialog box?

Tags: selenium

I have an application where user clicks on a button called 'Upload Patient signature'. This opens a File selection dialog box, where the user selects a file and clicks 'OK'. The file name appears in the box, the button gets disabled and the next button 'Upload' gets enabled. I have managed to send_keys to the first button to pick a predefined file which appears in the box. But the File open dialog box has opened and is waiting. Since it is not part of the application i am not able to get hold of it in Selenium. I have read that file upload/ download is not a good idea in Selenium for this very reason that the OS dialog box is out of control. What is the right approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Options in order of preference.

Option1 https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Does_WebDriver_support_file_uploads?

Option2 use java robot

Option3 use autoit script

Option4 use sikuli. Sample code can be found here http://automationsimplified.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/how-to-use-sikuli-java-api/

Options 2&3  you can get many links online for file dialog handling search.